# Aliasing Temporary Table (result of another query)

Tags: oracle, alias

I have some tuples as a result of a select query, and i want to insert those into another table.
I want to alias the temporary table (resultant table from select query) so that i can insert it into another table.

The table details (Stock):

```
create table stock(
MID number(4),
quantity number(7),
edate date
);
```

Values in First Table:

```
insert all
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (1, 10, '21-Mar-2016')
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (1, 20, '22-Mar-2016')
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (1, 30, '21-Apr-2016')
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (2, 40, '21-Jun-2016')
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (2, 50, '29-Jun-2016')
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (2, 60, '02-Jul-2016')
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (3, 70, '11-Jul-2016')
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (3, 80, '21-Jul-2016')
into stock (MID, quantity, edate) values (3, 90, '29-Jul-2016')
select * from dual;
```

Second Table (expirey):

```
create table expirey(
MID number(4),
quantity number(7)
);
```

Note: The second table is Empty, it contains no value.

My select statement to select values from the table stock is:

`select stock.MID, sum(stock.quantity) as tquantity from stock where stock.EDATE < to_date(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY') group by MID;`

now i want to insert the returned value into the expirey table, how can i do that by using temporary table aliasing?

Note: The resultant table column and column's datatype and the target table column and column's datatype is same, also the order of columns is also same.
**I don't want to use Nested query**, please help.

Sorry for grammar and Unclear question (if any confusion).

Comment: You can use the `INSERT` command itself.

Comment: it looks like your dbms is oracle. if so, tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Thankyou @PraveenKumar and but i already specified that i need help by doing this by **Temporary table aliasing**, not by nesting query. I will be really helpful for that help..

Comment: @vkp Can you help in temporary table aliasing, nomatter my DBMS, i can change it...